# Dynamically fill ListView from data model in javafx

Tags: java, listview, javafx, arraylist, model-view-controller

I've created a method to fill listviews with objects that fit the correct criteria:

```
public void setCourseModules(Collection<Module> modules) {

    t1UnSel.getItems().clear();
    t2UnSel.getItems().clear();
    t1Sel.getItems().clear();
    t2Sel.getItems().clear();
    yrSel.getItems().clear();

    modules.forEach(m -> {
        if (m.getRunPlan().equals(Delivery.TERM_1)) {
            if (m.isMandatory()) {
                t1Sel.getItems().add(m);
            } else {
                t1UnSel.getItems().add(m);
            }
        } else if (m.getRunPlan().equals(Delivery.TERM_2)) {
            if (m.isMandatory()) {
                t2Sel.getItems().add(m);
            } else {
                t2UnSel.getItems().add(m);
            }
        } else {
            yrSel.getItems().add(m);
        }
    });
}
```

and call it with:

```
smp.setCourseModules(course[0].getModulesOnCourse());
```

However, this is just a hardcoded entry to get the first course from the Array, I need to be able to dynamically change that index based on a comboBox selection, struggling to think how I can get the index of the course name as an int without hardcoding it...

Attached is the gist, the Student Setup class and the Controller are most important, Student class containing the comboBox and Controller has the course data declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to extend [M. le Rutte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1993392/m-le-rutte)'s answer

You could use

```
myComboBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
        //do something with selected item
    }
});
```

or

```
myComboBox.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
        //do something with selected index
    }
});
```

Comment: I did something similar

       public int getcboValue() 
          {int index = cboCourse.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
          return index;}
    
and called that inside the course[x], seems to work, how does it compare to your suggestion?

Comment: The difference is your code will only return a value when you call it in your code, mine will fire an action placed inside "changed" method everytime you select a value in your checkbox in UI

Answer (score 0):

My take on your question is that you need to get the selected combobox value. ComboBox has a `value` property:

```
public ObjectProperty<T> valueProperty();
```

> The value of this ComboBox is defined as the selected item if the
>   input is not editable, or if it is editable, the most recent user
>   action: either the value input by the user, or the last selected item.

Comment: That helped! Although, I didn't get the value, I created a method to get the selected index and I put that method inside the setCourseModules method. You definitely put me on the right tracks though, thank you!